# Sending command line arguments to a program

Tags: linux, command-line

In a Linux environment I have a socket program that sends data to a remote host.  The socket is started from within another program.  Its started with 3 paramters, a header, a server, and a port:

> mysocket A12345543DKSKGGDHH myserver 1234

Once the socket program is started, it continues to read stdin from the calling program that passes more data to the socket until its done.

I'm trying debug an issue, but I'd like to do it outside of the calling program by just running the socket program from the command line.  Starting it up with the initial handshake parameter, sever, and port is not a problem.... but I cannot figure out how to continue to pass the program the remaining values once its up and running.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: " how to continue to pass the program the remaining values" - are you talking about command line parameters, STDIN data or socket data?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question you want to redirect STDIN into your mysocket client like so?

```
mysocket A12345543DKSKGGDHH myserver 1234 << EOF
```